# How to add other filed on reply click of discussion board

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

I  have discussion board list with some filed like lookup and other.

Now problem is when user click on reply to particular Question then its only allow to add Body part not other field.

So is there any way to achieve to get all filed of list when user click on reply.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you need to show this fields in view  ?  should you elaborate more

Comment: yes. i want all fields in view when click on reply. default it just give for body i want add all filed when click on reply